# After removing a SCNNode we continue to detect node's collisions

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

Couldn't find a solution or an answer online ...

I'm building an AR game using SceneKit.
I have a `roomNode` which has several `wallNodes` as children.
The whole `roomNode` is set to detect collisions.
It all works perfectly fine.  Except ...

In the game I allow the user to tap a wall to remove it, at which point I would allow the user to walk through the missing wall without a collision being detected.  At least that's what I want to happen ...
After identifying the node with a hitTest, I just run:

```
node?.removeFromParentNode()
```

The problem is that I see the wall correctly being removed, but collisions continue to occur at the location where the `wallNode` used to be and now it's just empty space.

When I turn on debugging to show physics shapes and feature points like so:

```
sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints, ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin, SCNDebugOptions.showPhysicsShapes]
```

after removing the wall, I still see the outline of that removed wall as if it's still there.  Like a ghost of the wall still exists and it's still part of the higher level `roomNode` which still detects collisions.

Here are different things that I tried to solve this issue:

1. I saw in some other threads that after setting the node's `geometry` or its different `firstMaterials` contents to `nil` it would free some memory that was kept so I also tried doing that, but it didn't change anything.
2. I also tried setting the node itself to `nil`, but that didn't help either.
3. I tried changing that node's `physicsBody.type = .kinematic` so that even if a ghost remains in my scene, at least collisions wouldn't move the node, but that didn't work either.
4. I also tried changing the node's `physicsBody` different collision bitmasks to something that shouldn't cause a collision, but still no luck.
5. I tried to run `physicsBody.resetTransform()` for both the `roomNode` and for the node that was removed and that also did nothing.
6. The only thing that actually removed the ghost completely and allowed me to walk through the removed `wallNode` was if I recreated the whole `roomNode.physicsBody` like that:

   roomNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: roomNode!, options: nil))

So that did the trick.  But then, if my `roomNode` was previously moved due to collisions or if I moved the `roomNode` myself in code (using a pivot to reorient the room for the game's purposes), after recreating the whole `physicsBody`, the whole `roomNode` would redraw in a different location.
I can now try to figure out how to compensate for any node movement, but that can become very tricky if at all possible.

But there **should** be a correct way to remove some tapped node so that it would get completely removed from the scene without leaving any ghosts.

Don't know if this has any relevance, but the `roomNode` is defined globally as a property of my ViewController.
The different `wallNodes` on the other hand, are each created elsewhere locally and then added as child nodes.

If anyone knows how I could resolve this or if you have any clue I could try, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This definitely does the trick:

```
node?.physicsBody = nil
node?.removeFromParentNode()
```

`.physicsBody` instance property is optional:

```
var physicsBody: SKPhysicsBody? { get set }
```

Also, make sure that the removed node, not its parent node, had a physics enabled.

Comment: thanks! This does make sense.  My problem is that I need to set the physicsBody to the parent roomNode because if the user collides with any of the walls, I need to move the whole room as one.  If I set physicsBody individually to each wallNode then a collision will cause that specific wall to move and break the room as the rest of the walls won't move along.  So now I understand that when I remove a wallNode from the parent, it gets removed, but the physicsBody for the whole parent roomNode remains, even for the removed wall, until I recreate the whole parent's .physicsBody.

Comment: If there is any other way I could move the whole room node when colliding with a wall when the physicsBody is set for the individual walls, I'd love to know how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Please describe what is the purpose of this app and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks.  I cannot disclose everything, but I want the user to walk around the room without crossing through any of the walls and if the user hits a wall, I want the whole room to move with the user for that purpose.  So the room will remain static relative to the user if he tries to go through a wall. For that, I need the whole room to move as one.  I have a cylinder node with 0 opacity which is always at pointOfView which represents the user and I check collisions between that cylinder node and the roomNode.  Thanks!

Comment: In other words you need a `.kinematic` mode like this – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61753464/how-to-prevent-entities-from-overlapping/71230104#71230104. In SceneKit, it's a `kinematic()` type method – https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514776-kinematic. So, a character is `.kinematic`, walls – `.dynamic` (collisions must be enabled).

Comment: Collision shape in this case should be monolithic (not divided into separate parts).

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did. The cylinder I use as the user is kinematic and the roomNode is dynamic and I set the physcsBody to the whole roomNode. So now we're back to my original problem: if I remove a single wallNode, it gets removed, but the physcsBody for that wall as part of the whole room remains and I can't walk through it.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any problem - use a mono-object (whole-room-walls), do not use separate walls.

Comment: thanks again for getting back. Not sure I understand the last comment. I am giving the physicsBody to the whole roomNode as a monolithic node and all collisions happen with the whole room as a whole. But then in the game I need to remove a single wall and here after removing that wall from its parent, the physicsBody of the whole room still has that wall and I continue to collide with the removed wall.